# C# application ,localhost not able to resolve correct ip

Tags: c#, dns, client-server, localhost

I have a application (Office add-in), and 1 process which keeps running(background process required by main application).

Both are in Client Server Architecture (between processes).

We configure our client using Remote.configure(http://localhost:).

In few system, i see that when user changes the network (IP gets changed). my application still uses the old IP while resolving localhost.

There is no call for URL , everything is done at the background by .NET framework.

I have tried few thing, like changing to 127.0.0.1, updating my obselete API with latest one's , using command like ipconfig /flushdns, but nothing helps.

When you restart the process(background one). Everything is fine again.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Just to be clear, "localhost" points at 127.0.0.1 or ::1, and it doesn't change when the network changes. You need to be much more specific about what you're seeing.

Comment: Please help clarify what the exact issue is, and whether or not any of the proposed solutions are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very helpful if you could be a little more precise in the following areas:

- Can the application survive if the background process gets terminated WHILE the main application is running?
- Does the background process get terminated and begun multiple times WHILE the main application is running?
- Do you have full internal control of the background process (ability to modify code in it)?
- Do you have partial internal control of the background process (send commands to redirect, etc)?
- Do you have external flow control of the background process (ability to start/stop)?

Supposing based on your question that ...

- The application **CANNOT** survive if the background process gets terminated WHILE the main application is running?
- You **DO NOT** have full internal control of the background process (no ability to modify code in it)
- You **DO NOT** have partial internal control of the background process (no ability to send commands to redirect)
- You **DO** have external flow control of the background process (ability to start/stop)

Then your only real solution is to have the client stop the main process, go to the background process and restart it manually. While this is less than ideal, it is an unfortunate reality when you don't have internal control of either the application or background process.

Answer (score 0):

first of all why you are not using hostname? 
it seems that your app read the IP at startup and keep it without refreshing